# Как проверить URL адрес на валидность

Tags: http, golang, url, валидация

Хочу проверить URL адрес на валидность, но `url.Parse()` не выдает никаких ошибок и т.д, сам URL Адрес выглядит так `http://validate/`, это вообще не валидный URL, но не `url.Parse()`, не `govalidator.IsURL()` не выдают ничего подозрительного и никакой ошибки, в итоге я имею невалидный URL адрес.. Какими правильными и валидными способами можно валидровать `http/https` url адреса?

Comment: попробуйте зайти на сайт и скачать контент. если в контенте ошибка 404 - тогда он невалдный

Comment: Это вполне валидный URL. У пользователя в `/etc/hosts` или в локальном DNS вполне может быть такой хост.

Comment: @Ainar-G я тоже так подумал.. сейчас наверное напишу свою обертку к валидации нужным мне url адресов.

Comment: @michael_best вообще ошибка 404 не влияет на валидность URL адреса, невалидность url адреса означает ошибку парсинга этого адреса, ошибка парсинга схемы, параметров адреса и так далее.